Extracting files from a .tar.gz while keeping them gzipped
We have a pipeline that produces millions of .tar.gz files, each with one text file in them. We need to deliver the text files (gzipped, but not tarred).
I know I can easily pipeline the output via something like
tar xvf output-059a270d.tar.gz output-059a270d.txt && gzip output-059a270d.txt

But is there any way to take advantage of the details of the tar/.gz format to avoid having to gunzip and re-gzip the result?

Unfortunately, tar.gz is a gzipped tar file, not many tarred gzip files, so there is no way around ungzipping, grabbing the file from the tar and re-gzipping.

It's like getting the contents of a gift box without opening it.

Well, tar isn't exactly a closed gift box. It's a really linear format, as is gzip. I think the hard part of this would be to figure out the CRC and the size of uncompressed data within the tarball to rewrite the gz footer, without gunzipping the whole thing. Anyway, it was a long-shot, but I wondered if anyone had tried.

gzip is a streaming compression algorithm, not a block-based or keyframe-based compression algorithm. Any byte in a file potentially influences the compression of any byte that comes after it. Since there is a 512-byte tar header in front of the text file, that tar header changes the compression of the text file that comes after it. The gzipped text data by itself without the gzipped header is like dropping into a chat room. People are making references to things that happened earlier in the chat, but you don't know what they're talking about, so the chat makes no sense.

With GNU tar, you can avoid creating an intermediate file by using a pipe: tar xvfO output-059a270d.tar.gz | gzip >output-059a270d.txt.gz

As it stands, no, you can't. The .tar file, which is a tar header, the file contents, and a tar trailer, is gzipped as a single compressed stream. The compression of the start of the file contents can refer to matching data in the tar header, so the two cannot be split to construct a valid gzip stream of just the file.
However, you say "we have a pipeline". If you are in control of the generation of these .tar.gz files at the other end of the pipeline, then you can write them in a way that permits them to be split. Generate the .tar file with tar, and then feed that to your own code that applies gzip separately to the first 512 bytes, then to the file content, whose length you know, and then to the trailer, which will be all zeros. Those three gzip outputs can simply be concatenated. The concatenation of gzip streams is a valid gzip stream.
The result will be very slightly larger than the normal single gzip compression on the whole thing. But now you can look for the gzip members and pull out the middle one, which is what you want.
